# assertRedirectedToRoute not working in Laravel 5.1

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5.1

Controller code:

```
return redirect()->route('admin.patient.edit', $patientId);
```

Test code:

```
$this->visit(route('admin.patient.edit', $this->patient->id))
     ->press('Update');

$this->assertRedirectedToRoute('admin.patient.edit', [$this->patient->id]);
```

The error I get is this:

```
Failed asserting that Illuminate\Http\Response Object (...) is an instance of class 
"Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse".
```

I've printed out the response from the inside the test and inside the controller and it is in fact a RedirectReponse Object. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

`$this->assertRedirectedToRoute('admin.patient.edit', [$this->patient->id]);`

with

`$this->assertRedirectedToAction('MyController@myMethod');`

You are already on the route `admin.patient.edit`

One route should be a GET request for the `edit` method, and the other should be a `post` request for the `update()` method. You are redirecting to the same exact route (i.e the GET route). `admin.patient.update` would be a better name for that route

Answer (score 0):

I came across same problem.

Please refer to this [link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9743). People has been complaining. Turn out that the way we use it was wrong. You can refer to the right way [here](https://github.com/BootstrapCMS/CMS/blob/master/tests/BasicTest.php#L33)

Whenever we want to use `$this->assertRedirectedToRoute($route)` or `$this->assertRedirectedToAction($action)` or similar, we cannot use `$this->visit()`.

We must change it to `$this->get()`