# Laravel unit testing assertRedirectedTo

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I am working with some unit testing and i have difficult with one kind of assertions

```
  $this->assertRedirectedTo
```

Here is my very basic example controller code

```
        // example.com/form
        public function postForm()
        {
            $data = "my data";
            $this->mylogic($data);
        }
        private function mylogic($data){
            // operations with $data ... after some logics
            return redirect()
                ->route('Gracias')
                ->send();
        }
```

And this is my very basic example of my unit testing

```
        public function REDRIRECT_TEST()
        {
            $this->call('POST','form'); // it works
            $this->assertRedirectedTo('gracias'); // it fails
        }
```

and I get this error

```
        Failed asserting that Illuminate\Http\Response Object (...) is an instance of class "Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse".
```

This error happen when i use redirect inside another method

```
    private function mylogic($data){
        return redirect()
            ->route('Gracias')
            ->send();
    }
```

Any idea how to deal with `assertRedirectedTo` where the `redirect()` is  inside another method?

**Edited**.
Well, i re-thinked everythink and divided the logic from controller, now the logic is in another class and only return the correct route to redirect to the controller and my unit test pass.

Comment: aren't routes case sensitive? 'gracias' vs  'Gracias'

Comment: @vitr Yes it is, the redirection is working fine, the problem is when i want to test

Comment: So, why do you test in lower case? use the same case in the test

Comment: `assertRedirectedTo` accepts only string as parameter which is `gracias`.  On the other hand, `assertRedirectedToRoute` accepts `route name` has parameter wich is `Gracias`, that is the difference.

Comment: A few years on now, and you need $response->assertRedirect('gracias') as other methods removed

Comment: I've answered similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33946093/assertredirectedtoroute-not-working-in-laravel-5-1

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.7+ the methods are a little changed for the unit test.

```
        Session::start();
        $response = $this->call('POST', 'form', [
            '_token' => \Session::token(),
            'var' => 'value',
        ]);
        $response->assertStatus(302);
        $response->assertRedirect('gracias');
```